# Deploying Spring project without JSF dependencies to Payara causes javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager

Tags: spring, payara

Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager

But i do NOT use Java Server Faces, just a plain dynamic project with the whole spring dependencies on it.
I have tried different glassfish and java versions and absolutely none seem to work.

I absolutely do not understand anything anymore, what is this exception even??I tried to google and everyone who had this error was using JSF but i DONT.On my Eclipse at Facets i do not have JSF enabled

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by checking JSF and configurating it to resolve through Payara and then it worked even if i unchecked it back.Right now i am at same eclipse and project configuration that i had when i made this question and it's working.Must have been some weird Payara bug.